# Is this a namespacing problem?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am experiencing a strange behavior with very basic web service development. This question might be dumb but I think someone would be able to explain this observation.

I am developing a web service with a web method, MyWebMethod

```
MyWebMethod(MyEnum Param, .....)
```

Where,

```
public enum MyEnum : int
    {
       Type_1 =1;
       Type_2 =2;
       Type_3 =3;
    }
```

Now I am using my client to communicate with this service but for every request type, Type_1, Type_2 etc the service captures it as Type_1. As an example, if I create a break point at MyWebMethod in my web service, I see Type_1 as param1 type. I guess this is a problem with Namespacing. I cannot see any other defects on the code. Any Idea based on the experiences?

Comment: Definitely not a 'namespacing' problem. Whatever that may be.

Comment: Posting your `client` code may help..

Comment: So what do you expect instead? Do you instead want them as type int? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When enum is serialized, only its string representation is transferred through wire (names), not the values. I believe thats the reason you are getting the wrong values.

Check out this 2 articles for more info

1. [WebServices_and_Enums](http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/WebServices_and_Enums.html)
2. [Using enum in web service parameter](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/477452-using-enum-type-webservice-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WCF web service and a .NET 2.0 client generated with `wsdl.exe` for each value type in the method signature there will be a boolean parameter added called `XXXSpecified` which you need to set to `true`. Check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeneos/archive/2007/02/05/solving-the-disappearing-data-issue-when-using-add-web-reference-or-wsdl-exe-with-wcf-services.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your enum does not need to inherit from int. You are providing name and value in the enumeration, that should suffice. I am assuming all your code is .NET 2.0. As test , return an enumeration value from the webservice. Just to make sure XML Serialization is working as expected when the service is hit directly by the browser.